# c# mouse event sequence

Tags: c#, mouse

Question... why does this code only produce a message box "Down"? I'm not getting the Up. If I block down code, the up works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Mouse
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }   
        private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Up");                     
        }
        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Down");
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because focus is being lost to the message box window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are showing a `MessageBox`

Whenever a mouse down event happened a `MessageBox` will popup. The `MessageBox` Will be in foreground and the up event will be on the `MessageBox` instead of the form. Thus the up event in the form doesn't fire

Just do a `Console.WriteLine` instead of `MessageBox` and it should work as expected

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @samt, you thank people by clicking the green checkmark at the upper left of their answer.

Answer (score 0):

They will both fire if you remove the message box call. this is interferring with the mouse events because your loosing focus on the form. Instead of using message box try using...

```
  Console.WriteLine("MouseUp");
```

This will display in the ouput window and not interfere with the events